# Pseudo Elements not displaying when media queries make changes

Tags: css

I have :before and :after pseudo elements. I have these to change when the media rule has a screen width max-width:760px.

When the max width is 760 or > I should see a different graphic but the same :before and :after text content.

I see the new graphic but not the :before and after elements displaying.

I have tried adding the :before and after pseudo elements in the css under @media all and (max-width:760px) but without any success.

Does anyone have any idea why this is not displaying?

CSS

```
#infoGraph::before {width:100%; content:"Did you know..."; line-height:3rem; font-weight:bold; font-variant-caps:all-small-caps; font-size:1.4rem; margin-top:1.5rem;}
#infoGraph::after {width:100%;content:"Full text here..."; font-style:italic; font-size: 0.8rem}
#infoGraph {width:100%}
#infoGraph img {width:100%}

@media all and (max-width:760px){
#infoGraph{content: url('/site_images/new-graphic.png');}
}
```

Comment: two issue: (1) missing`{` (2) you are not targetting the pseudo element inside the media query

Comment: I do have - apologies - I forgot to include them - I will make it up so its correct. It still does not work

Comment: you have 2 issues, so you still have the second one

Comment: ok - if I add #infoGraph::before{content:"Did you know...";} and #infoGraph::after{content:"Full text here...";} it should work?

Comment: Hi Temani Afif - I had no luck with this - before/after text still does not display.

Answer (score 0):

Youare missing the brackets around the media rule:

```
@media all and (max-width:760px) {
  #infoGraph{content: url('/site_images/new-graphic.png');}
}
```

Comment: i feel like this is more of a comment than an answer